# PHP recognise computer

Tags: php, mysql, web, ip

Is it possible to recognize a certain computer with PHP? ( maybe with ip adress, although external ip adress applies to an internet connection not the seperate computer ).
So maybe it is possible to store certain variables in a database to recognize a PC later on?
Or create a hash of the variables and then check later on whether a PC matches the variables.

thanks in advance

Comment: One phrase... local data storage.  Also, keep in mind that anyone can see the data on their own computer, and if it looks like you might be trying to use a piece of data for security purposes, the end user may be able to break in either on purpose or accidentally by tweaking their local data.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to recognize a certain computer with PHP?

No, PHP is a server-side scripting language. What you probably want to identify a specific computer is the MAC address of the network adapter.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

All of the other implementations you will hear about to find this will be using a client side language, which would be outside the scope of this question.